# understanding the hotlinking of images

Tags: image, hotlinking

i have one image which works fine if reloaded in browser or if you enter in browser and click enter it will load else it will show nothing i have checked locally as well and it is not working if kept in img tag but if that image is opened seperately inh browser and then page is opened it is showing..

this is the image url

```
 http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/1440189/600full-chae--young-han.jpg
```

almost all img urls of listal.com is like that.

i have tried basic image loader

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body><img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/2359052/600full-kim-rossi-stuart.jpg" />  
</body>
```

is this geographically targeted??/ or something like this?
please suggest

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're saying that you can directly type in the image URL in a browser and see the image, but displaying it on a page fails, that sounds like hotlink protection. In .htaccess, HTTP_REFERER (domain) is checked against a list of known 'whitelisted' domains, and if it's not in that list, the request is failed. Direct browser invocation can be treated either way (always pass or always fail). That's the standard way of doing it; there are many variations you could do (restrict/allow by IP address, etc.).

Comment: @PhilPerry it fails when i check that html page loacally but that image opens when i enter in browser so it is not ip blocking atleast as for same ip is is working when we enter directly

Comment: If you have an HTML page that's invoking this image, your domain is probably not in the "whitelist" of allowed domains. There is no HTTP_REFERER if you type in the image URL into a browser, and the site owner can choose to handle it either way.